# "If you went" what tense is it? Is it a subjunctive mood?

Tags: tenses

I was watching an anime, and saw a sentence

> **If you went, you will die**

in translation. The context is *Some guy is forbidding his friend to go to some place*.

My question: Is it a subjunctive mood?

Comment: Movie/anime/etc. subtitles are never reliable, because they're barely translated by official/reliable translators. Some people with free time do the subs, with certainly a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Yes, but I learnt so much from movie, thanks Neeku. By the way for someone who voted me down would you give me a reason ? I think it would be usefull if Stackexchange provides a box for writing a "vote down reason" for better learning after, not only click and run. Just 2 my cents :)

Comment: Is there any chance that the character might already have been to that place?

Comment: No, they haven't been there @Araucaria . But they already know that is a dangerous place (boss villain place) so he tells to his girlfriend for not coming too because he's afraid about the safety..

Comment: OK, then as mplungijan says, it's incorrect!  :)

Comment: Does it mean i can use subjuntive or present tense like mplungjan said in this context @Araucaria ?

Comment: Yes, you can use either past simple, or present simple. Past simple will sound more hypothetical. (that means Present simple + *will* or past simple + *would*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect.

*If you went you would die* would be correct and subjunctive because it is a possibility

*If you go, you will die* would also be correct but not subjunctive just present tense because it is a certainty

Comment: So, what's the different? I mean, when to use subjunctive or just present tense ?

Comment: You can't really say for sure whether either is subjunctive or not, because the second person has no separate subjunctive forms (except _be_) in English.

Comment: I do not understand the comment. Wikipedia: "Some modal auxiliaries have a past subjunctive form. For example, the indicative will as in *He will come tomorrow* has the subjunctive form would as in *I wish that he would come tomorrow*." - in this case the would is predictive

Answer (score 2):

This is what the ESL people call the *second conditional*.

The [*first conditional*](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/firstconditional/menu.php) is used for something which we expect will happen, though it might not. The verb in the conditional is in the present, and the main verb is often future, but it can be present:

> If you go, you will/may/can see him

The [*second conditional*](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/secondconditional/menu.php) is for things that didn't happen, or we think are unlikely to happen, but are talking about what if they did happen. For most verbs, this uses the simple past in the condition, and the "conditional" (with *would*) in the main clause:

> If you went, you would see him

(the implication is that you can't go, or probably won't go).

In the special case where the verb is *to be*, many people use the special form *were* instead of *was*

> If I were Superman, I would fly there

(Of course, if the subject is *we* or *you* or *they*, *were* is the normal form anyway). This *were* is the last relic of the otherwise defunct verb form known as the "subjunctive" - for every other verb in the language, it is identical with the simple past, which is why I describe it that way rather than talking about the subjunctive.

Comment: An, I believe, more common way of formulating the second conditional is to use the past compound subjunctive "If you were to go, you would see him".

Comment: @DanSheppard You nailed the correct past subjunctive form. I don't know why some people label this as a 'relic'. I'm only 39 and in my circles all the properly educated know this form.

Comment: Because "you were to go" is indistinguishable from the past. Only in the first and third person singular is it a special form (_I/he were_) - and many speakers no longer use this special form.

Answer (score 2):

There is a context in which the sentence would be correct, but it's a relatively contrived one:

"I heard you were planning to go to Chernobyl in late 1986 to participate in the creation of the sarcophagus around the destroyed reactor. I don't know if you actually did it. If you went you will die."

Normally the assumption is that *if you went* is either in the (1) past subjunctive, in which case the conclusion would also have to be in the past subjunctive: "If you went you would die." (*Would* is the past subjunctive of *will*.) Or if it is (2) simple past, then the conclusion is very likely also past tense. ("If you went, you died." - Doesn't make much sense in this case due to the nature of the conclusion. One rarely addresses dead people in this way.)

My contrived example is for (2) with a conclusion that lies still in the future.

Comment: I’m not convinced that talking about this in terms of “subjunctives” is necessarily all that useful.  Certainly not on the modal side, that’s for sure.

Comment: As with mplungjan’s answer, there is no way to tell whether _would_ is a subjunctive or not. There's no real reason for it to be—a subjunctive conditional construction would be unnecessary, really, when a simple conditional would do the job just as well.

Comment: Interesting version. "If you went, you will (eventually) die" - which is still a certainty :)